# Is it possible to abort executing query without setting "timeout" attribute in IBatis?

Tags: oracle11g, ibatis

Consider,
A query is taking more than a minute to retrieve the data (Due to larger volume of data) from the database.
I know that, we can set "timeout" attribute in the select tag (For a single query alone) or "defaultStatementTimeout" attribute in settings tag (SqlMapConfig.xml - For all the query) to forcibly terminate the query in execution.

```
<select id='uniqueName' parameterClass='java.util.Map' resultClass = "java.lang.String" timeout="60">
```

or

```
<settings useStatementNamespaces="false" defaultStatementTimeout="60"/>
```

By doing the above configuration, IBatis will throw "User cancelled request" error and terminates the execution.

Do we have any other way to terminate the execution?

**My Scenario is:**

When user requests for 3 years data, it takes more than a minute to fetch data from the database.
In the meantime, when the user requests for 1 day's data or sends a "cancel" request, I have to forcibly terminate the previous execution (3 years data retrieval) because it is affecting performance even with limited number of users.
**NOTE**
I didn't used any of the setting above.

Please provide me solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a resource limit by modifying the Profile associated with the database user.